# How to access to a variables defined and assigned by another API

Tags: c++, qt

Sorry for my newbie question. but I'm working on C++ since few times and I would like to manage some informations related to a device. the goal is to get a name of device in a variables and all another class to access to this variable.

I have defined a class device:

```
class Device {
public:
    int value;
    ...
}
```

in my main.cpp,

```
int main (...)
{
    Device MyDevice;

    MyDevice.value = 10;
    Browse ui;
    ui.show();
}
```

in a browser.cpp, I would like to be able to get the MyDevice.value and display it. I'm not really sure how to do it. browser.cpp is the cpp code which will display some information supported by a UI in Qt. the current ui is displayed using the ui.show() api.

Comment: I would connect a signal from Device to a slot on your Browse class. This is the Qt way of doing this assuming the value in your Device object will change.

Answer (score 1):

`value` should be a `private` member of Device, otherwise you'd be exposing private data of the `Device` class to its clients. Although your code will run, this is considered a bad programming practice that violates the encapsulation principle. Once you make your `value` a private data member, in order for the clients of your `Device` class to access it, you should provide a getter method say `getValue` that returns `value`. Once you have this place, you should model your browser to accept a reference to a `Device` object. You could do this in the constructor of `Browser` or accomplish this through a member function of `Browser`. Once your `Browser` knows about your `Device` instance, then it can call `getValue` to retrieve `value` so it can display it in the UI. In summary, your code would look something like this:

```
class Device {
public:
   int getValue() const {
     return m_value;
   }
private:
   int m_value;
};

class Browser {
public:
   Browser(const Device& device) :
   m_device(device) {

   }
   void displayValue() {
     someWidget.show(m_device.getValue());
   }
private:
  const Device& m_device;
};
```

I'd start with a good beginner's book on C++ (and Object Oriented Programming) to familiarize yourself with concepts of encapsulation, reference, etc.

Comment: In this case I prefer to use a pointer parameter as it prevents passing a temporary object which will go out of scope. Why isn't your getter const?

Comment: Good point about getter being const. Edited my answer accordingly. How does a pointer help? If the code that creates `Browser` doesn't ensure that the `Device` instance lives as long as `Browser` does, then regardless of whether you have a pointer or a reference you are looking at a dangling entity.

Answer (score 0):

My Browser interface is defined by:

Browser.cpp

```
FileBrowserMainWindow::FileBrowserMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FileBrowserMainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
...
}

FileBrowserMainWindow::~FileBrowserMainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and Browser.h

```
namespace Ui {
class FileBrowserMainWindow;
}

class FileBrowser : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit BrowserMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FileBrowserMainWindow();
    Ui::FileBrowserMainWindow *ui;

private:
    const Device& m_device;
};
```

I'm not quite sure to understand how to get the value in the Browser.h / cpp

I'm calling this UI in the main.cpp in the main

```
FileBrowserMainWindow ui;
//Ui::FileBrowserMainWindow ui;
ui.show();
```

Comment: You should edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Holy smokes! You edited my answer so it includes your question!! Sorry, there are multiple things wrong here, you'd have to study C++ basics to gain some familiarity before you dive into coding.